# NOT Like Operater is not working with dynamic SOQL

Tags: apex

String searchQuery = 'SELECT Id, OwnerId, WhatId,Reminder_Date_Time__c, WhoId, Record_Type_Name__c, Task_Type__c,Assigned_Date__c, Task_Status__c, ActivityDate, Subject, Attended_By__c,Is_Assigned__c';
        searchQuery = searchQuery + ' FROM Task';

```
    integer count = 0;
    integer searchListSize = taskSearchCriteriaList.size() + taskSearchCriteriaListForDate.size();

    for(SearchCriteriaWrapper searchWrapper :taskSearchCriteriaList){

        if(count == 0){
            searchQuery = searchQuery + ' WHERE';

        }


        if(searchWrapper.operator == 'Equals'){
            searchQuery = searchQuery + ' (';
            integer i = 0;
            for(String value :searchWrapper.systemObject.Text__c.split(',')){
                if(i != 0){
                    searchQuery = searchQuery + ' OR';
                }

                searchQuery = searchQuery + ' ' + searchWrapper.fieldName + ' LIKE \'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(value.trim()) + '\'';

                i++;
            }
            searchQuery = searchQuery + ')';
        }
          if(searchWrapper.operator == 'Not Equals To'){
            searchQuery = searchQuery + '(';
            integer i = 0;
            for(String value :searchWrapper.systemObject.Text__c.split(',')){
                if(i != 0){
                    searchQuery = searchQuery + 'OR';
                }

                   searchQuery = searchQuery + 'NOT ' +searchWrapper.fieldName + 'LIKE\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(value.trim())+'\''; 

                i++;
            }
            searchQuery = searchQuery + ')';
        }
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by “not working”. Do you get an error, no results, etc. also where in your code are you getting the values to compare? Is it a local variable, passed in via the method, in another class? Sometimes you have to extract the values to a local variable

Comment: no results for Not Equals To                                                                       problem in query searchQuery                                                            
searchQuery = searchQuery + 'NOT ' +searchWrapper.fieldName + 'LIKE\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(value.trim())+'\'';

Answer (score 3):

There is no "NOT LIKE" operator.

The correct form is "(not field like term)", as in:

```
taskQuery = taskQuery + '(NOT '+ searchWrapper.fieldName + ' LIKE \'' +
            String.escapeSingleQuotes(value.trim()) + '\')';
```

Answer (score 0):

your Field name is dynamic and your SObjectName is also Dynamic so write following syntax with condition

refer this example

```
String textResearch =String.escapeSingleQuotes(value.trim());
String query = 'Select Id, ' + selectedField + ' from ' + selectedObject + ' where ' + selectedField + ' like \'%' + textResearch + '%\'';
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709237/create-a-dynamic-soql-query-using-variable-objects

Comment: This really does not answer *this* question. The poster is *not* apparently using a dynamic sObject name, but in any case, the question is about the correct syntax for negating a `LIKE` condition.

Comment: @DavidReed -- The second-to-last single quote is on the wrong side of the percent sign -- I'll fix that -- but, I'm surprised to say, I think it does. I have no idea what searchWrapper is, and the use of __r is wrong, but if we ignore that (like the answer does), and we assume taskQuery was something like, "SELECT Id FROM ' + objectSelected + '  WHERE ' , then you do get a well-formed query.  The answer does correct all that.

Comment: @Shane Steinfeld hie it's Dynamic SOQL without using Select Operater